# 'runtime error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error' when trying to input UDF through range.formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, udf, vba

I'm trying to put a user defined function in cell J3 through `Range.Formula` method, but I encounter **`application-defined or object-defined error`**, can someone please tell me if it is even possible to put UDFs in cells that way? I tested the function by inputing it manually and it works. The code is:

```
Range("J3").Formula = "=EmpiricalDist($AF$1;$AD$1;0.95;E3;1;-1)"
```

where `EmpiricalDist` is the mentioned UDF. I'm working in excel 2013.

Comment: Range("J3").Formula = "=EmpiricalDist($AF$1;$AD$1;0.95;E3;1;-1)"

Comment: @Sorceri Sorry, your answer was the code I used from the beginning, I was trying to put it as a string in cell J3, without the .Formula suffix, but it gave the same error

Comment: The ; are what cause the error but without seeing your EmpiricalDist function I dont know what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Sorceri thanks, replacing the semicolons with commas solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Chang line

```
Range("J3").Formula = "=EmpiricalDist($AF$1;$AD$1;0.95;E3;1;-1)"
```

Into

```
Use Range("J3").FormulaLocal = "=EmpiricalDist($AF$1;$AD$1;0.95;E3;1;-1)"
```